# Session and mysql_query doesn't insert data to table

Tags: php, mysql, session

Mysql_query inserts data to "orders" table when placing the order, but it doesn't insert data to "order_detail" table.

It should take the data from the Session 'cart', but seems to fail.

I've taken some html code away for simplicity and just left the button, but shouldn't matter.

```
<?php
require_once('connect_to_db.php');
include("includes/functions.php");
session_start();

if ($_REQUEST['command'] == 'update') {
    $customerid = mysql_insert_id();
    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $result = mysql_query("insert into orders values('', '$date', '$customerid')");
    $orderid = mysql_insert_id();

    $max = count($_SESSION['cart']);
    for ($i=0; $i<$max; $i++) {
        $pid = $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
        $q = $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'];
        $price = get_price($pid);
        mysql_query("insert into order_detail values ($orderid,$pid,$q,$price)");
    }
    die('Thank You! your order has been placed!');
}
?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script language="javascript">
function validate(){
    var f=document.form1;
    f.command.value='update';
    f.submit();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form1" onsubmit="return validate()">
<input type="hidden" name="command" />
<input type="submit" value="Place Order" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is how I store data to Session 'cart'

```
function addtocart($pid,$q){
        if($pid<1 or $q<1) return;

        if(is_array($_SESSION['cart'])){
            if(product_exists($pid)) return;
            $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
            $_SESSION['cart'][$max]['productid']=$pid;
            $_SESSION['cart'][$max]['qty']=$q;
        }
        else{
            $_SESSION['cart']=array();
            $_SESSION['cart'][0]['productid']=$pid;
            $_SESSION['cart'][0]['qty']=$q;
        }
    }
```

Comment: are the values stored in session properly??

Comment: a) there's no error handling in your script. `mysql_connect`,`mysql_select_db` and `mysql_query` can fail in which case they return FALSE. In that case `mysql_error()` can tell you more about the actual error. b) You might want to check what $max actually is, e.g. by printing it in your die(message). c) The mysql_* extension is deprecated and removed in the upcoming version 7 of php, better [pick another API](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) to connect to your MySQL server

Comment: Be aware that the old mysql_* extension which you're using is deprecated in version 5.5 of PHP (the current version) and is being removed from version 7 (the next version). You need migrate over to using either the mysqli_* extension or PDO

Comment: I added my code for storing data to session, Niranjan. 
My database connection works good, Volker, and $max seems to always print value 1.

Comment: Add quotes to your query:  `insert into order_detail values ('$orderid','$pid','$q','$price');`
BTW: You should consider controlling the possible error in the query: `if (!mysql_query(...)) die(mysql_error())` or something similar.

Comment: Added or die(mysql_error()); after mysql_query for order_detail and got: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: I was trying to insert 4 values but table had 5 columns. I deleted one column from table and now it's inserting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. In HTML every form should have method ("GET" or "POST") or action   (file) in case you are using the same file (this case) just put the filename there.
2. In PHP in this case you shouldn't use request but post or get, because request handle both, usage of post or get might be a little bit faster.
3. You can optimize your html file without javascript, this javascript isn't necessary.
4. You should avoid using mysql_query use PDO (data objects) instead.
5. I guess orderid and productid are same, you should use only one.
6. You should add '' into your second query.
7. You should name the columns in your table like: "INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...) VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)", check if you aren't adding more values than your table in mysqlDb can handle.

Try the code below, it might work better, but set the filename in action and set the column names. there

```
<?php
require_once('connect_to_db.php');
include("includes/functions.php");
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $customerid = mysql_insert_id();
    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO orders (column1,column2,column3) VALUES('', '$date','$customerid')");
    $orderid = mysql_insert_id();

    $max = count($_SESSION['cart']);
    for ($i=0; $i<$max; $i++) {
        $pid = $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
        $q = $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'];
        $price = get_price($pid);
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO order_detail (column1,column2,column3,column4) VALUES('$orderid','$pid','$q','$price')");
    }
    die('Thank You! your order has been placed!');
}
?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form name="form1" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>">
   <input type="submit" name="update" value="Place Order" />
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This improves nothing and some blatant errors are still there.

Comment: E.g.: twice usage of the same variable.

Comment: Step 7 pretty much solved it, I was trying to insert 4 values but table had 5 columns. I deleted one column from table and now it's inserting.